# Any StackIdeas/StackBrainstorm.com?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a StackOverflow/StackExchange-branch for brainstorming ideas? For instance, is there a place I could go to and brainstorm with/get ideas/get help from others on the architectures of my upcoming programs/code?

In other words, just a place where you could present your ideas for programs, and get help on how to implement/solve those ideas with code. Or, just present your ideas and get help getting started/getting pointed in the right direction(for instance, which programming languages would be best for that project, etc.).

Comment: If you wanna give it a try, you can always ask for [community's thinking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and post a proposal.

Comment: If you're standing in front of a whiteboard, we have a place like that.  If you're standing in front of a dart board, nopes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no such Stack Exchange site.

Stack Exchange sites are question and answer sites - this is the model they are built on and what they are good for.

There is no support for the kind of threading / mind-mapping requirements that a brainstorming site would need.

Answer (score 6):

This could possibly be a valid topic in chat of any site in which the general topic is appropriate, although of course any given chat room may or may not welcome such questions.

It would not be appropriate as a proper question on any of the main sites, due to how broad of a question it is.